# need help for this background worker code

Tags: .net, multithreading, f#, backgroundworker

I get this code example from Expert F# by Don Syme from chapter 13

```
open System.ComponentModel
open System.Windows.Forms

let worker = new BackgroundWorker()
let numIterations = 1000

worker.DoWork.Add(fun args ->
    let rec computeFibonacci resPrevPrev resPrev i = 
        //compute next result
        let res = resPrevPrev + resPrev

        //at the end of the computation and write the result into the mutable state
        if i = numIterations then
            args.Result <- box res
        else 
            //compute the next result
            computeFibonacci resPrev res (i+1)
    computeFibonacci 1 1 2)

worker.RunWorkerCompleted.Add(fun args ->
    MessageBox.Show(sprintf "result = %A" args.Result) |> ignore)

//execute the worker
worker.RunWorkerAsync()
```

i knew that this code compute fibonacci number, but my question is, is there any way that i make the function for compute fibonacci and then wrap it in the background worker code? with example would be better :) thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to slightly simplify the solution by Ankur - you don't need to use `lazy` values in this case. The simplest way is to declare the `computeFibonacci` function first and then call it from the `DoWork` event.

The important point that you need to change `computeFibonacci` to return the result instead of storing it to `args` because `args` are only available when called from `DoWork`:

```
let numIterations = 1000

let rec computeFibonacci resPrevPrev resPrev i = 
    //compute next result
  let res = resPrevPrev + resPrev

     //at the end of the computation and write the result into the mutable state
  if i = numIterations then 
      // Return result from the function
      res
  else 
      //compute the next result
      computeFibonacci resPrev res (i+1)
```

Then you can create background worker that calls `compueFibonacci` and storest the result in `args`:

```
let worker = new BackgroundWorker()

worker.DoWork.Add(fun args ->
    // Call fibonacci and store the result in `Result`
    // (the F# compiler converts number to `obj` automatically)
    args.Result <- computeFibonacci 1 1 2)

worker.RunWorkerCompleted.Add(fun args ->
    MessageBox.Show(sprintf "result = %A" args.Result) |> ignore)

worker.RunWorkerAsync()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer mr thomas. But what do you mean by the F# compiler converts number to 'obj' automatically? is the BackgroundWorker class do that or else?

Comment: @Yabert - I mean that you don't have to call the `box` function explicitly (as it Ankur's solution).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.. Using a bit of "laziness" as well as higher order function using currying , there may be other technique as well. Infact using this you can wrap any function which produce a result.

```
let worker = new BackgroundWorker()
let numIterations = 1000

let rec computeFibonacci resPrevPrev resPrev i = 
            let res = resPrevPrev + resPrev
            if i = numIterations then
                box res
            else 
                computeFibonacci resPrev res (i+1)


let wrapper (result:obj Lazy) (args:DoWorkEventArgs) = args.Result <- result.Force()


worker.DoWork.Add( lazy (computeFibonacci 1 1 2) |> wrapper)

worker.RunWorkerCompleted.Add(fun args ->
    MessageBox.Show(sprintf "result = %A" args.Result) |> ignore)

//execute the worker
worker.RunWorkerAsync()
```

Comment: thanks ankur. your code worked too. but i prefer the code from Mr Thomas because its more simple. But thank you very much :)